# Primary Key and Index in same table

Tags: mysql, indexing, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpMyAdmin for creating a database based on a previous development that a colleague did. I am assigning an autoincremental column as a primary key for my data. In phpMyAdmin this is shown as a golden key near of the name of the column, but in the database of the previous version there is also a silver key near the golden one and says "index" when I put the mouse on.

I'm almost new in MySQL management and I don't get the importance of the use of this silver key, becuase the primary key is an index itself.

Comment: Please learn to use the commandline `mysql` tool.  With it, you can copy and paste things like `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to help us see what is going on.  That will provide complete and unambiguous information; colored keys is only partial info.

Comment: Hi @RickJames, when I use `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM <table_name>:` I see the same information in a table with only a primary key ( which is shown in phpMyAdmin UI as a golden key) and another with the silver key. I've tried to find this attribute in other ways but until now I couldn't

Comment: When I pick over the silver key the SQL is `"ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD INDEX(`column name`);` But the silver key doesn't disappear, seem there is not a way to disable once is select

Comment: There are few different types of indexes in MySQL, primary is only one of them.

Comment: Consult the manual pf phpmyadmin. Those icons are shown by the tool, not MySQL itself. Probably the gold key is the PK, and the silver key is another key... or maybe an index.

Comment: Sorry, but I need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>` to explain what is going on.

Comment: @RickJames here is the query: `Cycle_has_SubCycle | CREATE TABLE `Cycle_has_SubCycle` (
  `idcycle` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `idsubcycle` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `idsubcycle` (`idsubcycle`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idcycle` (`idcycle`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |`

Comment: Also is worth to point that in the UI I can select two colums as a primary key, whereas in the command line I get an error. Later I check in the command line and the two columns are in fact as primary key. The documentation says: "There can only be one primary key per table and it is named always PRIMARY". I don't know how I can have two columns as primary

Comment: @DavidLópez - There is a distinction between `PRIMARY KEY(a,b)` (which is OK) versus `PRIMARY KEY(x), PRIMARY KEY(y)` (which is _not_ OK).  The former says that the pair (a,b) uniquely defines each row of the table.